# Страница 404 при переходе с гугл поиска

Tags: wordpress, seo, breadcrumbs, yoast

Есть сайт, настраиваю Yoast SEO.
Не могу разобраться.
В гугл выдаче выдает www.milanew.com/комбинезоны/
В реальности, ссылка http://www.milanew.com/product-tag/kombinezoni-odejda-w/
При переходе с гугла, получаю ошибку 404
В чем проблема? Где свзять их?

Answer (score 0):

У вас в текущей карте сайта `http://www.milanew.com/sitemap_index.xml` такой url `www.milanew.com/комбинезоны/` отсутствует. Т.е., Google выдаёт вам старую информацию.

Отправьте сайт на переиндексацию с помощью Google Search Console.

Comment: Метку товара Комбинезоны я только вчера добавил, это не старая страница, такой и не было никогда. Если в гуглу набрать rozetka компьютеры, он выдаст hard.rozetka.com.ua/Компьютеры‎, и там при переходе, ссылка работает, перенаправляет на реальную. Проблема,я так думаю, где-то в этих SEO заголовках, которые берутся автоматически из названия записи(рубрики), но почему то никуда не ведут

Comment: Google ниоткуда не берет эту инфу, только из ваших sitemap

Comment: Вчера??? Да никак, ни при каких условиях, Google не проиндексирует ваш сайт за сутки.